# absolutely positioned div inside scrollable area not extending beyond viewport

Tags: html, css, overflow

**Description**

When a containing div with `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll` contains a series of `display:inline-block` elements such that it pushes the content wide enough to create a scrollbar, a subsequent `position:absolute` element with `left:0;right:0;` fails to fill past the scrollable viewport, such that scrolling the containing div, also scrolls the absolutely positioned element.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4mhr1ev/4/)** (position the width of the "result" window such that you get a horizontal scrollbar, then scroll left and right to observe the `.row-cover` div's background failing to extend into the scrollable region)

**Question**

I am looking for a CSS only solution. What CSS changes should i make in order to "cover" a `.row` with an element such that the content underneath it is "obscured"?

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-outer-container">
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row-cover"></div> <!-- BACKGROUND IMAGE DOES NOT EXTEND FULL WIDTH -->
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="column-inner">
                        10
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="column-inner">
                        10
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="column-inner">
                        10
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="column-inner">
                        10
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="column-inner">
                        10
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FOR BREVITY THE FOLLOWING ROWS ARE MINIFIED -->
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="row-cover"></div><div class="columns"><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div><div class="column"><div class="column-inner">10</div></div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
*, :after, :before, input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.outer-outer-container{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    right:20px;
    bottom:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.outer-container{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:auto;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
.row{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.columns{
    /* remove "gaps" between inline-block items */
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
}
.column{
    /* reset font-size and line-height from "gaps" between inline-block items fix */
    font-size:1rem;
    line-height:1.4;
    display:inline-block;
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
.column-inner{
    height:48px;
    font-size:1.2rem;
}
.row-cover{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,rgba(255,255,255,.5),rgba(255,255,255,.5) 25%,rgba(204,204,204,.5) 25%,rgba(204,204,204,.5) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.5) 50%) top left fixed;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Updated to include outer-outer-container that has `overflow:hidden` to disable `body` scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Set the outer-container div to `display:table`.

https://jsfiddle.net/d4mhr1ev/1/

Comment: this is reliant upon the page's overflow then not the `outer-container`, when `overflow:hidden` is applied to the `body` you cannot scroll https://jsfiddle.net/d4mhr1ev/2/

Comment: I have updated my fiddle to include an outer-outer-container to better display this: https://jsfiddle.net/d4mhr1ev/4/

Comment: That's because the outer-container doesn't overflow. To make the outer-container overflow, add an outer-inner-container inside outer-container and make that display:table instead. https://jsfiddle.net/d4mhr1ev/5/

Comment: that new fiddle does not appear to be working on OSX Chrome 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit) http://imgur.com/aqOPdrJ